# Incorrect jQuery mouseover() function assignment inside for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem is this:

```
for(i=0;i<grid.length;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<grid[i].length;j++)
    {
        console.log(current_grid);
        var current_grid = grid[i][j];
        current_grid.bgc("red");
        current_grid.dom.mouseover(function()
        {
            console.log(current_grid.ident);
        });
    }
}
```

The console.log always returns the last element in the loop. So this is the full code and the output on mouseover is always "td_3_3".

```
function main(){

var canvas = new Element('body','canvas','div','absolute');
canvas.fullscreen();
canvas.bgc("red");

var tablet = new Element('#canvas','tablet','table','relative');
tablet.fullscreen();
canvas.bgc("black");
tablet.dom.css("table-layout","fixed");

var row_1e = new Element('#tablet','row_1e','tr','');
var td_1_1 = new Element('#row_1e','td_1_1','td','');
var td_2_1 = new Element('#row_1e','td_2_1','td','');
var td_3_1 = new Element('#row_1e','td_3_1','td','');

var row_2e = new Element('#tablet','row_2e','tr','');
var td_1_2 = new Element('#row_2e','td_1_2','td','');
var td_2_2 = new Element('#row_2e','td_2_2','td','');
var td_3_2 = new Element('#row_2e','td_3_2','td','');


var row_3e = new Element('#tablet','row_3e','tr','');
var td_1_3 = new Element('#row_3e','td_1_3','td','');
var td_2_3 = new Element('#row_3e','td_2_3','td','');
var td_3_3 = new Element('#row_3e','td_3_3','td','');

var row_1 = [td_1_1,td_2_1,td_3_1],
    row_2 = [td_1_2,td_2_2,td_3_2],
    row_3 = [td_1_3,td_2_3,td_3_3];

var grid = [row_1,row_2,row_3];

for(i=0;i<grid.length;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<grid[i].length;j++)
    {
        console.log(current_grid);
        var current_grid = grid[i][j];
        current_grid.bgc("red");
        current_grid.dom.mouseover(function()
        {
            console.log(current_grid.ident);
        });
    }
}
}

function Element(myparent,ident,type,position)
{
this.ident=ident;
this.myparent = myparent;
this.html5 = '<'+type+' id='+this.ident+'></'+type+'>';
this.dom = this.draw_element();
if (position != '')
{
    this.dom.css("position",position);
}
}

Element.prototype.draw_element = function()
{
$(this.myparent).append(this.html5);
return $('#'+this.ident);
}

Element.prototype.fullscreen = function()
{
this.position("0","0");
this.resize("100%","100%");
}

Element.prototype.bgc = function(color)
{
this.dom.css('background-color',color);
}

Element.prototype.position = function(x,y)
{
this.dom.css({'left':x,'top':y});
}

Element.prototype.resize = function(x,y)
{
this.dom.css({'width':x,'height':y});
}
```

Comment: So, what is your question exactly?

Comment: Thanks, yes. I agree this may be a duplicate. Difficult question to word, though. So no need to downvote.

Answer (score 2):

`current_grid` is assigned a value while the loop runs, after the loop exits, the value of `current_grid` is the last item in the array.  Click events happen *after* the loop exists.

You want something more like this:

```
for(i=0;i<grid.length;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<grid[i].length;j++)
    {
        console.log(current_grid);
        var current_grid = grid[i][j];
        current_grid.bgc("red");
        // you have jQuery, use it
        $(current_grid).click(function(event,ui){
            console.log($(this).id);
        });
    }
}
```